# How to disable TableTools buttons in DataTables?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, datatables

I am using the latest version of DataTables plugin in my Ruby on Rails app and I want to disable the TableTools buttons(Copy, CSV, Excel, ...) that show up by default, I have tried the following code but it removed the whole table tools panel.

```
$('#myTable').dataTable
  'dom': 'T<"clear">lfrtip'
  oTableTools :
    {
      aButtons: nil
    }
```

Please help!

Comment: You want to disable them coz you don't need them or you want them to be enabled and disabled based on different acions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this .. remove the `T` option from the `dom` value

```
$('#myTable').dataTable
  'dom': 'lfrtip'
```

The `T` option triggers the initialisation of TableTools.

Comment: Well i need table tools but i dont want the buttons, i just need the row click functions and stuff

Answer (score 1):

Provide `"aButtons": []` inside the `tableTools` property in settings.

Answer (score 0):

remove options like csv,excel
remove B - works 100%

```
 t = $("#tbl_item").DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        info: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '../Ajax/Ajax_Section?option=getAllPhantomsAndItems&user_srno=',
            data: function (data) {
                delete data.columns;
            }
        },
        columns: [
                    { "data": "abc" },
                    { "data": "srno" },
                    { "data": "reference" },
                    { "data": "categoryName" },
                    { "data": "makeName" },
                    { "data": "sapCode" },
                    { "data": "logisticOffer" },
                    { "data": "priceUsd" },
                    {
                        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return '<a class="btn btn-warning" onClick="AddToSection(' + full.srno + ',' + '\'' + full.type + '\')" href="javascript://">Add To Section</a>';
                        }
                    }
        ],
        order: [[1, 'desc']],
        select: true,
        dom: 'lrtip',
        responsive: true,
        buttons: true
    });
```